# Conflicting PartialEq implementation

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I would like to write PartialEq for my struct holding a generic type. I'd like the comparison to fail when the types are not equal in both structs and do an actual comparison when they are equal. Is this possible to do?

Here is the code:

```
fn main() {
    let first = Foo { inner: 0_u32 };
    let second = Foo { inner: 0_u32 };
    let third = Foo { inner: "text" };
    
    println!("{}", first == second); // print true
    println!("{}", first == third);  // print false
}

struct Foo<T> {
    inner: T
}

impl<T> PartialEq<T> for Foo<T> 
where T: PartialEq 
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &T) -> bool {
        self.inner == other.inner
    }
}

impl<T, U> PartialEq<U> for Foo<T> 
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &U) -> bool {
        false
    }
}
```

This produces an error of conflicting `PartialEq` implementations. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

[Here is Rust playground link to the code.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=06022f1f7cdc6954737028c27e6e82e5)

Comment: Only with the nightly-only specialization, and it is unsound.

Comment: What is unsound?

Comment: The feature. It can be used to trigger UB in safe code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chaiym mentions in the comments this can only be done on nightly with `#![feature(specialization)]`:

```rust
#![feature(specialization)]
//…
impl<T, U> PartialEq<Foo<U>> for Foo<T>
where
    T: PartialEq<U>,
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &Foo<U>) -> bool {
        self.inner == other.inner
    }
}

impl<T, U> PartialEq<U> for Foo<T> {
    default fn eq(&self, _: &U) -> bool {
        false
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b80325f46b0258f50fdfcec661bfd9c2)